# Cors errors for Lambda fucntion using AspNet Core and API Gateway

Tags: asp.net-core, cors, aws-api-gateway

I have this strange issue with CORS using APIGateway HTTP API. I am hosting a AspNetCore WebAPI and am able to call and authenticate using Postman. So the API is up and running. I have setup CORS rules for my AspNetCore API and tested it locally and it works.

But when hosted behind APIGateway HttpAPI I get the follow:

```
Access to fetch at 'https://xxxxxxx.execute-api.eu-xxxxx.amazonaws.com/api/values' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.
```

I have tried to add CORS settings to Aws HTTP Api in the console as following:

[image]

And a lot of other variants to test it out. But still get errors.

My Javascript client is pretty basic as the following:

```
 var idToken = await auth.currentUser.getIdToken(true);

  const requestOptions = {
    method: 'GET',
    mode: 'cors',
    referrerPolicy: 'origin',
    headers: { 
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + idToken
    },
  };

  var response = await fetch('https://xxx.execute-api.xxxx.amazonaws.com/api/values', requestOptions);
```

And my AspNetCore CORS Settings:

```
services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy(name: MyAllowSpecificOrigins,
                                  builder =>
                                  {
                                      builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:3000")
                                      .AllowAnyHeader().AllowCredentials().AllowAnyMethod();
                                  });
            });
```

.....

```
app.UseRouting();

app.UseCors(MyAllowSpecificOrigins);

app.UseAuthorization();
```

Really have no idea what is going wrong. I have tried disabling CORS on aspnet core side, changing up the settings and allowing any origin.

Hosted plenty of other services without any problems with CORS and this service does run locally with cors from 2 different domains without problems.

I am using APIGateway HTTP API Jwt token Authorizer. Don't know if that is causing any problems. But as stated earlier, I am able to send messages from postman with bearer tokens and getting responses.

Comment: Install-Package ```Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors```

Comment: Pritom -> read the question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56783833/cors-error-with-aws-lambda-and-net-core-webapi  you can found some ideas for resolve your issue.